# Is that any option for search tabs in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

that is  we have opened many tabs.In that tabs i want to search specific tab. Please tell if any ext or option or add-on in chrome or firefox.

Comment: Do you mean searching a specific tab for content?  Or do you mean search for a specific tab with a specific title and get a sort of handle to it?  Also, are you looking for an end-user extension or are you asking how to implement this feature in your own extension?

Comment: search for a specific tab using title from all opened tabs. i want end user extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox has this functionality built in.  If you just start typing in the URL bar and the first character you type is `%` followed by a space, the rest of what you type will be treated as a search on the titles and urls of open tabs in all Firefox windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the site to be asking for help finding extensions that do end user tasks such as this so I'll answer your question explicitly as well as explain how to do it programatically.

The short answer is, yes one extension that will allow you to do this can be found here:
[Tab Title Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-title-search/fbgmfenfjogaoibifpgolehkibnfalgn)

The long answer is, in order to find all tabs with a certain name, you need to use the [chrome tabs API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html)

I whipped up a short piece of javascript to demonstrate how to have an extension that will create a popup with a search box that you type the desired tab title into.  If the tab is found, it will be listed below the search box.  If you click on the listing, you will switch to the tab.

```javascript
// Function to search for tabs
function searchtabs() {
   chrome.tabs.query({
      title: ""
   },
   // Callback to process results
   function(results) {
      // Place holder for the tab to process
      var foundTab = null;

      // Text to match against         
      var queryText = document.getElementById("textToSearchInput").value;

      // Div to place divs of matched title in
      var queryAnswerDiv = document.getElementById("foundTabsDiv");

      // Clear the current children
      while (queryAnswerDiv.hasChildNodes()) {
         queryAnswerDiv.removeChild(queryAnswerDiv.lastChild);
      }

      // Iterate over all the results
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
         // Keep track of the tab that is currently being processed
         foundTab = results[i];

         // If we have a title containing our string...
         if (foundTab.title.indexOf(queryText) > -1) {
            // Create a new div
            var tabDiv = document.createElement("div");
            // Set its content to the tabs title
            tabDiv.innerHTML = foundTab.title;
            // Let it know what the tabs id is
            tabDiv.tabToSwitchTo = results[i].id;
            // Allow for users to click on the representing div to switch to it
            tabDiv.onclick = function() {
               // Make the tab selected
               chrome.tabs.update(this.tabToSwitchTo, {
                  selected: true
               });
            };
            // Append the created div to our answer div
            queryAnswerDiv.appendChild(tabDiv);
         }
      }
   });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var inputField = document.getElementById("textToSearchInput");
   inputField.focus();
   inputField.onkeydown = searchtabs;
});
```

Also, if this is more what you are looking for rather than the extension that I linked, let me know and I can pack this extension.

**Edit:**
Fixed an error in using the wrong ID to get the input field as well as not getting the first letter of the title (use `indexOf() > -1`)

Comment: Thank u :)for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 0):

An extension that does this is [Tab Hero for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-hero-faster-tab-navig/jphcjpibbjcofhgfbjhojaeiiepbcioc) ($0.99 Chrome extension). It searches through all of the open tabs (across multiple windows) and offers to switch to the filtered tab. Try and see if it works for you.